# Cheerio attributeStartsWith selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-selectors, selector, cheerio

I'm using `cheerio` to `scrape` a `website`. I want to select all element where the id starts with a certain value. But when I use the [`attributeStartsWith`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like in `jQuery` I get the `malformed attribute selector` syntax error.

This you can do in `jQuery` to select all `div` elements starting with 'question-summary-'

```
$('div[id^="question-summary-"')
```

My `node` code looks like this

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load('https://stackoverflow.com/')

console.log('text', $('div[id^="question-summary-"').text())
```

How can I accomplish this in `cheerio`? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax bug :)

Change

`console.log('text', $("div[id^='question-summary-'").text())`

to

`console.log('text', $("div[id^='question-summary-']").text())`

Full Code

```
const $ = cheerio.load('https://stackoverflow.com/')

console.log('text', $("div[id^='question-summary-']").text());
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using

```
$("[id|='question-summary']")
```

instead ?

as |= is looking with what is inside the '' followed by an hyphen.

Comment: maybe your problem is the ending hyphen in your selector?

Comment: Unfortunately the `contains prefix` selector doesn't work neither :(

Answer (score 0):

I now see that I have a typo and strangely it's fully excepted by jQuery. Fixed the typo and now it works. Cheerio was right, and jQuery should be more unforgivable.

Old selector

```
$('div[id^="question-summary-"')
```

New selector

```
$('div[id^="question-summary-"]')
```

Notice the bracket at the end.

Strangely the first selector is fully excepted by jQuery. To test the old selector go to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), enter F12 and paste it into the console. You will see that both selectors are working.

Answer (score 0):

I've been curious about your problem...

putting this simple code together, had no problem parsing the front page of stackoverflow...

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request')

try {


  request('https://stackoverflow.com/', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      $('[id|=question-summary]').each(function (i, element) {
        console.log(element.text());
      });
    }
  });

}
catch (e) {


  console.log(e);

}
```