# How do i select <a> with aria-label in cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, express, cheerio

I am currently building a scraper which scrapes data from newspaper sites based on the keyword I am looking for, such as "environment" and "climate". But I have recently encountered a site where I couldn't simply check if the text has my desired keywords. Its HTML is written in this way

```
<a aria-label="Ravaged by floods, Bangladesh pitches plan to adapt to climate impacts" class="card-with-image-zoom" href="https://en.prothomalo.com/environment/climate-change/ravaged-by-floods-bangladesh-pitches-plan-to-adapt-to-climate-impacts">
```

Here is how i am looking for keywords using cheerio-

```
 const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const specificarticles = [];
$('a:contains("climate"),a:contains("environment")',HTML)
```

How do i check the keyword availability of this specific HTML using cheerio?

Comment: You can use `.getAttribute()` to get the value of the aria-label from the `<a>` tag. Then check that string for the keywords. If so, you'll want to store the hyperlink to the article.

Answer (score 3):

If it uses normal selectors, try

```
$("a[aria-label]")
```

for all and

```
$("a[aria-label*=Bangladesh]")
```

for example to get one with the word Bangladesh in it

Comment: `$("a[aria-label*=Bangladesh]")` or `$("a[aria-label]:contains("climate)")` isn't working

Comment: What does the "contains" look for? Are you sure it accesses the attributes

Comment: Using my current code i have accessed other sites but now when I am trying to access this site's attribute(site: https://en.prothomalo.com/environment/climate-change/) it can't find anything.

Comment: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#-selector-context-root-

Comment: it should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600513/cheerio-attributestartswith-selector

Comment: It only works after the page has fully rendered. The content is Ajaxed in

Comment: I for example cannot find `aria-label="UK` unless I look in the rendered page