# Why are Javascript attribute query selectors valid when missing the end bracket?

Tags: javascript

After reviewing MDN's [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) docs, which points to the MDN [CSS Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) doc for defining an attribute selector, which points to the W3C's [Attribute selectors](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/selectors/#attribute-selectors) docs, I haven't been able to understand why an attribute selector with a missing end bracket is valid.

Some examples of valid attribute query selectors with the end bracket omitted:

```js
// This question's title
const t1 = document.querySelector("[id='question-header'")
console.log("t1", t1)

// Even works when using a case insensitve query
const t2 = document.querySelector("[id='question-HEADER' i")
console.log("t2", t2)
```

Here's a runnable example:

```js
const t1 = document.querySelector("[id='content'")
console.log("t1", t1)

// Even works when using a case insensitve query
const t2 = document.querySelector("[id='CONTENT' i")
console.log("t2", t2)
```

```html
<div id="content">Javascript attribute query selector</div>
```

Is this because JS allows close-enough syntax? Or?

**Edit** I did find this other question, [Cheerio attributeStartsWith selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600513), which had a missing end bracket and was the root cause of the issue. However, as one of the answers pointed out, JQuery allowed the missing end bracket while Cheerio failed.

Interesting enough, I actually found this issue while using Puppeteer and noticed two of my selectors missing an end bracket, yet everything had been running w/o issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this. Assuming I'm interpreting the spec's rules correctly (which I may not be) the section on how to handle error handling when parsing css would seem to allow for this.

a.) In The DOM standard for querySelector

> The `querySelector(selectors)` method steps are to return the first
> result of running [scope-match a selectors string](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#scope-match-a-selectors-string) *selectors* against
> this, if the result is not an empty list; otherwise `null`.

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselector

b. ) That links to section 1.3. Selectors. Looking at section 1.3.1:

> To **scope-match a selectors string** *selectors* against a *node*, run these steps:
>
> 1. Let s be the result of [parse a selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#parse-a-selector) selectors. [SELECTORS4]

c.) *Parse a selector* links off to the csswg v4 draft, which doesn't go into as much detail about error handling as the v3 draft. The v3 draft states (emphasis added by me):

> § 2.2. Error Handling
>
> This section is not normative.
>
> When errors occur in CSS, the parser attempts to recover gracefully,
> throwing away only the minimum amount of content before returning to
> parsing as normal. This is because errors aren’t always mistakes—new
> syntax looks like an error to an old parser, and it’s useful to be
> able to add new syntax to the language without worrying about
> stylesheets that include it being completely broken in older UAs.
>
> The precise error-recovery behavior is detailed in the parser itself,
> but it’s simple enough that a short description is fairly accurate.
>
> - At the "top level" of a stylesheet, an  starts an
>   at-rule. Anything else starts a qualified rule, and is included in the
>   rule’s prelude. This may produce an invalid selector, but that’s not
>   the concern of the CSS parser—at worst, it means the selector will
>   match nothing.
> - Once an at-rule starts, nothing is invalid from the
>   parser’s standpoint; it’s all part of the at-rule’s prelude.
>   Encountering a  ends the at-rule immediately, while
>   encountering an opening curly-brace <{-token> starts the at-rule’s
>   body. The at-rule seeks forward, matching blocks (content surrounded
>   by (), {}, or []) until it finds a closing curly-brace <}-token> that
>   isn’t matched by anything else or inside of another block. The
>   contents of the at-rule are then interpreted according to the
>   at-rule’s own grammar.
> - Qualified rules work similarly, except that
>   semicolons don’t end them; instead, they are just taken in as part of
>   the rule’s prelude. When the first {} block is found, the contents are
>   always interpreted as a list of declarations.
> - **When interpreting a list of declarations, unknown syntax at any point causes the parser to
>   throw away whatever declaration it’s currently building, and seek
>   forward until it finds a semicolon (or the end of the block). It then
>   starts fresh, trying to parse a declaration again.**
> - **If the stylesheet
>   ends while any rule, declaration, function, string, etc. are still
>   open, everything is automatically closed. This doesn’t make them
>   invalid, though they may be incomplete and thus thrown away when they
>   are verified against their grammar.**
>
> After each construct (declaration,
> style rule, at-rule) is parsed, the user agent checks it against its
> expected grammar. If it does not match the grammar, it’s invalid, and
> gets ignored by the UA, which treats it as if it wasn’t there at all.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#error-handling

Bullets 3-5 allow for a css rule to end without proper closing delimiters. In a stylesheet, a rule is a "[prelude](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#syntax-description)" (selector) followed by a set of css declarations wrapped in braces. A selector with no rules after it is invalid and discarded.

```html
<style>
div[foo]
</style>
```

and is treated the same as a selector without a proper closing delimiter

```html
<style>
div[foo
</style>
```

A selector with rules after it missing a closing `;` and/or `}` is a complete selector + rule, and so it is still valid. Both of these are valid:

```html
<style>
.foo {
    color:red;
</style>
```

or

```html
<style>
.bar {
    color:blue
</style>
```

Finally, given that `document.querySelector` only requires a *selector with no rule following it*, I would conclude that a selector with a missing closing delimiter is valid according to the spec. You can see the same behavior with the `:is` pseudo class selector:

```js
document.querySelector("div:is(.foo");
document.querySelector("div:is([foo");
```

Comment: "*Parse a selector links off to the csswg v4 draft, which doesn't go into as much detail about error handling as the v3 draft*" - it does further link to css-syntax-3, [parse something according to a CSS grammar](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#parse-grammar). And as the non-normative overview says, "*The precise error-recovery behavior is detailed in the parser itself*" - more concretely, when reaching the input stream end during [consuming a simple block](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#consume-a-simple-block), it simply returns the block (despite being a "parse error").

Comment: Excellent man. And those CSS examples perfectly illustrate the error handling. Kudos! And @Bergi comment brings it full-circle. Cheers!